# CSS grid min-content not shrinking to correct size

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm new to grids and I'm trying to understand some cell sizing concepts.

I have a container that is set to `display: grid` and a `main` element centered in the grid where the `min-content` column/row is.

```
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content 1fr;
}

.main-container main {
  grid-column: span 1
  grid-column-start: 2
  grid-row: span 1
  grid-row-start: 2
}

canvas {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

and html

```
<!-- page -->
<html>
...
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <main>
      <canvas />
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/coderatchet/pen/ZrVBdG)

The application will center around the happenings of the canvas, and due to the nature of aspect ratios in canvas rendering, I want the center grid cell to conform to the size of the canvas and not the other way around.

I expect that due to both `main` and `canvas` being `border-box`'ed and the size of the canvas being absolute, then the `main` element should theoretically not effect the calculated `min-content` height. this isn't the case for width but somehow the height adds 4 extra pixels.

[image: 4px high gap]

Where did these extra height pixels come from and how can I ensure they don't appear

> Setting the height of main explicitly to 600px does solve the problem, however this is redundant information and I anticipate there is a solution not involving hardcoded height bandaids.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [White empty space below Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746835/white-empty-space-below-canvas)

Comment: You're encountering baseline alignment. It's a feature of inline-level elements. It's explained here: [Mystery white space underneath image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31444891/3597276)

Comment: The problem isn't with the CSS grid at all, but rather is caused by the use of the `<canvas>` tag. It's `inline` by default, so doesn't take up the full height of the parent. While the marked duplicate will provide a solution that will work, there's more information available in [**Getting inline-block element's height to fill the parent**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404485/) and [**Image inside div has extra space below the image**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image).

Comment: Thanks, That worked! just changed the canvas `display: block;`.

Comment: @Michael_B -- Noticed my poor choice of words there and corrected that already :)

Answer (score -2):

Please give `float:left` to canvas or add height to `main{height:300px}` and give height to  `canvas {height:100%}`

Comment: Sorry, but if you read the question and the comments this would not be your answer.